# Twitter and Facebook Sharing in iOS application using Social Framework in iOS 8.4 adding URL not working in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

Adding URL in Twitter and Facebook sharing in iOS application using Social framework for iOS 8.4 is not working.

Only `setInitialText:` method is working but not the `addURL` and `setTile` methods.

My code is as follows:

```
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {

        SLComposeViewController *fbFeed = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
        [fbFeed setInitialText:self.travelogueTitle];
        [fbFeed addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.saveTraveloguePublishedURL]];
        [fbFeed setTitle:@"My Trip's Memories"];
        NSLog(@"Save published url:%@",self.saveTraveloguePublishedURL);
        NSLog(@"Share published url:%@",travelogue.publishedUrl);
        // [fbFeed setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mvm064/MVPWeb/ViewTravelogue?travelogueId=OB1YlsTz/gngmCUTESuqlQ=="]];

        [fbFeed setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {

            if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled) {
                    NSLog(@"The user cancelled.");
            }
            else if (result == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) {
                NSLog(@"The user posted to Facebook");
            }
        }];

        [self presentViewController:fbFeed animated:YES completion:nil];
    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no method in `SLComposeViewController` to `setTitle`. `SLComposeViewController` is basically `subclass` of `UIViewController` so giving you facility to set title of `SLComposeViewController`. It will not going to post on `Facebook`. For post on `Facebook` you have method called `setInitialText`.

I have tried with your code and its get uploaded successfully, you can check out in following image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you Abhishek for the response.

Comment: Thank you Abhishek for your response. I want to know how exactly can we add URL and an image to our post along with Initial text like mentioned in below link.

http://www.appcoda.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/SocialSharing-Facebook-Post-with-Image.jpg

Please do help me out to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance.